# Create csv file from mysql results with php?

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

So I'm trying to make a .csv file which after I will download it,but the problem is that the rows are not going aranging properly.
I am using fputcsv.

```
$tot.="$codcomanda,$clientnume,$brandnume,$numeprod,$um,$cantitate,$updatare";
$list =array(
    array('Comanda','Client','Categorie','Produs','UM','Cantitate','Actualizare'),
    array($tot),
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

The variable $tot is from a `while` statement and it gets its variable from different queries and I cannot find a php code on the internet that is for my needs.I've tried several ways to try and make it work but nothing.
I've tried making `$tot` different ways but none work,either it $tot.=
The csv file should have something like.

- Title line,
- Line 1,
- Line 2,
- etc

But my csv shows like

- Title line,
- "Line1,Line2,etc"

I've tried making `$tot` different ways but none work,either the csv show like this or doesn't display no content at all.

---

Solved: Using fwrite i've solved it.

```
$tot.="$codcomanda;$clientnume;$brandnume;$numeprod;$um;$cantitate;$updatare;\n";
$tot2="Comanda;Client;Brand;Produse;U.M;Cantitate;Actualizare;\n$tot";

    $file = fopen("file.csv","w");
    fwrite($file,$tot2);
    fclose($file);
```

And it write's it like it should.

Comment: do you by any chance try to view this on Windows with something as simple as notepad? there's a good chance that your CSV is linux formatted, which uses different line endings. A good editor would show them as separate lines if it's this simple.

Comment: Same on notepad and MS excel 2012.And yes indeed im using ubuntu 12.04 with Gedit as text editor and Libreoffice Calculator.

Comment: Kindly download and check on notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: First of all thanks for your time, same stuff is showing in notepad++, the problem is that i need to make array($tot) see it for every line to make it something like array($line1),array($line2)...etc.If i set $tot.=($codcomanda,$clientnume,$brandnume,$numeprod,$um,$cantitate,$updatare); and at $list i set only $tot there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

Try like the following example

```
     <?php
          $list =array(
                       array('Comanda','Client','Categorie','Produs','UM','Cantitate','Actualizare'),
           array('P1','C1','CL1','2','2','Ct1','A1'),
           array('P2','C2','CL2','2','2','Ct2','A2'),
          );

       $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

     foreach ($list as $fields) {
     fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

     fclose($fp)
   ?>
```

Comment: you need to specify each lines in your csv as array,Or you can download a csv by setting headers and using implode() function

Comment: yeah but the problem is I cannot make different lines as arrays,only all lines as one array.I managed to resolve using fwrite.

Comment: Yeah,updated my post.Thank you for your interventions.I cannot set your answer as usefull since i have 1 reputation.Hopefully I will find a way in the future to write my code with fputcsv.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line before the calling of fopen(): ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true)